# Discord Modal read questions via requests

Tags: python, automation, discord, request, discord.py

a client asked me recently if I can find a way to read discord modals using requests or discord.py

I can't find anyway to do it, do y'all know how can I read the questions inside a discord Modal?

I tried to analyze the requests using the developer tools (chrome) and I dint  find anything like the text/question in them

Answer (score 0):

You can't read the modal answers with the requests module, however you could try to use the requests module to send data to a webhook etc.